# Sending SIGTERM to `script` results in a zombie process

Tags: linux, kill

I am implementing a simple system to run jobs remotely via SSH. My goal is to run the job within a `screen` and record all its output using `script` and upload the typescript to a server when the job terminates. I am, however, struggling with handling SIGTERM properly (e.g., when the remote machine is about to shut down) as the `script` process does not terminate upon receiving SIGTERM (instead the process that runs within `script` becomes a zombie).

Assume the following command:

```
script -e -q -c 'ping www.google.com'
```

Using `killall -TERM script` to send a SIGTERM signal to the `script` process seems to pass the SIGTERM signal to `ping` (which terminates), however, it becomes a zombie process and the `script` does not terminate:

```
> ps -aux | grep ping
karel    16460  0.0  0.0  10852  2732 pts/2    S+   12:57   0:00 script -e -q -c ping www.google.com
karel    16461  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   12:57   0:00 [ping] <defunct>
```

If I understand it correctly, the `ping` process is a zombie because the parent `script` process is still observing it. However, is it possible to make the `script` stop observing the process and gracefully terminate (while flushing the typescript)?

Comment: This looks like a bug in `script`. I am facing this issue with `script` version 2.31.1 but not with version 2.29.2.